# adb pull dynamically created file path

Tags: android, linux, bash, shell, pull

I know I can pull file from android like this

```
adb pull /sdcard/file.txt
```

But I try to do something else

First I search for the last edited file like this

```
tmp123=$(adb shell ls /sdcard/file.* -aR . | head -n 1)
```

and then I try this

```
adb pull $tmp123
```

and I get something like this

```
' does not existsdcard/file.txt
```

I bet it is something very stupid mistake but I am stack for hours
Thanks

Comment: what return `$tmp123`? something `/` like missing?

Comment: Your `ls` options seem unnecessary (and also `ls` returns more than one result per line - what if you just try `tmp123=$(adb shell ls -1 /sdcard/file.* | head -1)`?

Answer (score 0):

There may be a '\r' new line character at the end of adb output

You may try something like this:

```
tmp123=$(adb shell ls /sdcard/file.* -aR . | head -n 1 | tr -d '\r')
```

refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26746853/strange-behaviour-of-adb-pull-in-bash-script?answertab=votes#tab-top) for a possible solution